# -bash: pg_dump: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, homebrew

I'm trying to pull a production database locally for my rails app. My local postgres version was too low so I needed to update to Postgresql 9.6.5 from 9.4.1.

I installed Postgres 9.6.6 via Homebrew as such:

```
brew install postgresql@9.6
```

Then ran:

```
brew services start postgresql@9.6
```

However, when I try to do `pg_dump` I get `-bash: pg_dump: command not found`.

I also tried updating my path as such:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\@9.6/9.6.6/bin:$PATH"
```

Any idea what I need to do to get `pg_dump` to work?

Comment: did you restart your machine ?
or try doing source ~/.bash_profile and open new window.

Basically brew install most of times dont require EXPORT command settings

Comment: I doubt this will help, but on my (linux) system pg_dump is in /usr/bin, but  is actually a symlink to /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper. I think your first step is to find out where pg_dump is.  Maybe something like: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_dump

Comment: my pg_dump is located here - `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\@9.6/9.6.6/bin/pg_dump`. Which is what I tried to add to my path as above

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding this to my ~/.bash_profile did the trick:

`export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\@9.6/9.6.6/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 2):

For those who have this issue on Mac even though Postgres path is correctly added on your .bash_profile I found that running pg_dump directly from the Terminal does the job.

Just open your Terminal and type:

```
pg_dump -U username your_database > db_dump.bak
```

I tried the ff approach and I got the same error:

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_dump -U username your_database > db_dump.bak

bash: pg_dump: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed PostgreSQL by pgadmin4 in Mac, you could find the pg tool in

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/{version}/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get path to work in Cygwin but could browse to my pg bin directory (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin) and run it directly from there.

Answer (score 0):

For windows what worked for me is to add the Postgres to global vars from env, not `~/.bash_profile`,

- Go to Edit the system environment variables
- Then Environement variables
- Then Path then add the location of bin of postgres in my case `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\`
- Click ok on each open window
- Close and reopen your visual code
- Run your command

See [Setting Windows PATH for Postgres tools](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/setting-windows-path-for-postgres-tools) for more details